# How to hide/remove an option that's already submitted in codeigniter dropdown menu for the next form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form  with dropdown menu where its options loaded from a mysql table.
The form requires all of those options submitted once, and removed from the dropdown menu thereafter, until every option is removed. Any idea how to do this? I haven't tried anything. I'm very clueless where to start

Notes: I'm using `php5.6`

Comment: If i understood your question correctly. You can put the select box as `multiple` and by default select all using `selected` attribute for `<option>` tag, and when you submit you will get all the options as an array. Then save the options in a session, and check the options with the session, if the option is in the session don't show the option again.

Comment: how to save options in a session? im still unfamiliar with "session" concept, sorry

Comment: use `$_SESSION['options'] = $_POST['selectbox_name'];`
and then check the options by looping with `$_SESSION['options']`.
remember you have start the session to use sessions in PHP using `session_start();`

Comment: is this possible with codeigniter 2.x? your solution is spot on and very easy to grasp, thanks.

Comment: i guess it would be possible, am using codeigniter 3.x, and it works fine on 3.x versions. because even codeigniter is built using Core PHP, it supports all the Core PHP functions.

Comment: great, i'll try to implement this and come back with results.

Comment: Ok.. good luck..

Comment: storing/retrieving from the session ONLY applies when the session is active. what if the user logs out or clears their cookies? is this form serving multiple users? because a session would only apply to one user, and other users would have all the options available even if one option was already submitted from another user.  i think it would be best to define what you are trying to accomplish better, including why you want the options to be removed. otherwise, it is hard to find a solution.

Comment: okay, what i'm trying to do is building a rating questionnaire that have a dropdown menu with few teacher names populated from a "teacher" table. The person filling it  is required to give a rating to all of the teachers in the list, to be able to complete the questionnaire. I want to prevent duplicate entry by removing  an option thats already been submitted. (i have no idea if there is a better way please let me know !!)

Comment: ok, then storing everything in a session is a good way of doing it. just make sure you don't commit anything to the database until the questionnaire is completely. someone could just dive out of the questionnaire half-way through and you'd be left with a corrupted data-set. another consideration would be if you wanted them to be able to complete the questionnaire at a later time. in which case you'd need to store their answers in a database immediately as they go along, then you can cross-reference the teachers that they already reviewed with the full list of teachers removing the ones reviewe

Comment: either way, this will be a undertaking for a beginner and your question isn't really answerable when seen in the context of this site.